# Laravel Eloquent Model, can not explode string results

Tags: laravel, explode

Here is my database

I want to get the number of received letters but it does not work. This is my code:

```
 $letters3=LettersModel::orderby('id','desc')->get();
$parts= array();


    foreach ($letters3 as $letters) {

 $parts = explode(',',$letters->girandeh);


foreach($parts as $key=>$parts2){



if($parts2==$email){


echo count($parts2);


}


}


    }
```

It will be displayed in the following way [here is my db][2]

Comment: milad jan soal ro bad porsidi, barat edit mikonam!

Comment: What is the result ? error ?

Comment: Please, properly format your code so is more readable.

Comment: Show us an example of the content of `$letters->girandeh`.